# Identify Hot and Neutral Line on Vintage Clock

Tags: wiring, electric-motor

I am working on a vintage clock, and in order to make it safer, I would like to replace the cord with a more modern UL-approved cord.

First things first, I am trying to identify the hot and neutral lines of the current cord, but I'm having a hard time distinguishing between the two.

The metal prongs appear to be exactly the same size. The wire itself doesn't have a ridged side, but it does have one side that is slightly embossed with the words "General Electric L Flamenol"

[image: vintage plug without obvious identifiers]

Looking at what I think is the clock motor, there doesn't appear to be any indicator of a positive or neutral side.
[image: vintage clock motor]

As far as I can tell, the only obvious marker is the "General Electric L Flamenol" label on one side of the cord -- does anyone know if that indicates power or ground?

Below is an image of the clock model 8125 and power details for reference.
[image]

Any other feedback or safety recommendations on this undertaking are very appreciated

P.S. The ink is a little blotchy, but looks like the bottom label says "220V" -- but that seems far too high to work on a normal outlet. Is is more likely that it's actually 120V and coincidentally looks like 220V?

Answer (score 1):

After more research, I realized that this question has been answered already -- I just didn't have the right terminology for it. When the prongs of a plug are the same size, they are "non-polarized" and don't have a hot and neutral.

I am looking to convert a non-polarized plug to a polarized one. According to [this stack exchange thread](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/22213/can-i-use-a-polarized-cord-and-plug-to-rewire-a-non-polarized-clock) it doesn't matter which way I wire it when going from non-polarized to polarized, so long as my gauge is the same or larger on the new plug so that it caries the old electrical load safely.